# Read form data from doc or rtf file with java

Tags: java, forms, ms-word, rtf

i have a word document with a form that is filled by users and , after that, it is saved. I would like to access form field data from a Java application in order to automatize some business process. 
I have tested Apache POI but it is unabled to access form elements. 
Is there some api to access form element data with java?

Comment: What did you specifically fail to do with POI? I'd recommend you to post another question like "why this code that uses POI does not work?" You probably have chance to get a good answer and solve your problem.

Comment: I thought it was clear, when i say it is unable to access form's elements, i mean it actually doesn't support accessing form's fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [`Class FFDataBaseAbstractType`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/model/types/FFDataBaseAbstractType.html) (`org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.types`).

> The FFData structure specifies form field data for a text box, check box, or drop-down list box.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) which allows you to [access form fields and data in Java applications](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/form-fields-in-aspose-words.html). The API is quite simple and easy to use. The component is a simple Jar file which is easy to deploy with your application. Also note that you do not need to install MS Word in order to use this component. Please see if this might help in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi Shahzad, the main problem is the licence. I was looking for an opensource solution.

Comment: Right. In fact, it was not explicitly mentioned in your post that you were looking for an open source solution. I think, instead of saying 'some api', you should say 'some open source api'. I hope this might help. :)